# How do i convert my data into numeric data on pgAdmin4 . I keep getting the same error

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I'm fairly new to SQL but i cant find a solution the following problem.
Ive made some tables in pgAdmin4 and put in a CSV file containing the data for the tables. I want to replace the X and Y data to numeric data but i keep on getting the same error while i make slight adjustments to the code:

```
select distinct replace("X",',','.')::numeric, replace("Y",',','.')::numeric
from dataset_raw
```

The error that I receive is:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "6.171.983.937"
>  SQL
> state: 22P02

[in this picture it shows the result i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U3OC.png)

Comment: This works fine, replacing the dots . : SELECT replace('6.171.983.937','.','')::NUMERIC;

Comment: Yes. A numeric field doesn't contain thousand separators. They are only added by the software that you are viewing data from. So as Frank Heikens says, you just remove the `.` by replacing with an empty string.

Comment: `select to_number('6,171,983.937', '999G999G999.999') 6171983.937`. The resulting value will be `numeric`. See [Data formatting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) and the `to_number()` function and the section *Table 9.28. Template Patterns for Numeric Formatting*.